How to force specific currency on checkout page in magento 1.8
I'm using USD and NOK currencies on my Magento shop.
The base currency in USD, and I want when user visits the checkout, the NOK currency display, not the USD (even if user choose USD currency from the switcher in product page)
Simply, I want to display only NOK price in checkout page.

in your checkout controller  in public function indexAction()
Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode('NOK');
Note : It is not recommended to modify core file so you need to use some module or override and do this.
